# Rails: custom routes nested custom routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

Can I do custom routes nested within a custom route already?

Say

```
localhost:3000/prof/3
```

with

```
match 'prof/:id' => 'professionals#show', :as => :prof
```

I'd like to do more custom routes:

```
localhost:3000/prof/3/services/2
```

Right now I have this:

```
resources :professionals do
  resources :services, :defaults => { :servicable => 'professional' }
end
```

this gives me something like:

```
/professionals/:professional_id/services/:id
```

I'm still learning rails methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply specify the `path` option for your resource to put it at a specific location.

```
resources :professionals, path: '/prof' do
  resources :services, :defaults => { :servicable => 'professional' }
end
```